# Automatically search an app in Play Store or App Store

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, cordova

I am currently developing app using Cordova / Phonegap. In my app, I want to check if Google Maps app is available. I am using this [plugin](https://github.com/lampaa/org.apache.cordova.startapp) for android and it works. It goes to the MAPS app since it is available. When I disabled the Google Maps app, it went to the error callback which is perfect. In the error callback, I tried to open the Play Store app, which also works. What I am trying to do is, when the Play Store app is opened, I want to the Play Store to open the MAPS page for me. Is it achievable? Also I want to know if there is a similar plugin like this for iOS. Or should I just open the app using an InAppBrowser? I am new to Web Technologies so I need some advice on this.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For android:

Install inAppBrowser. make a system call like

```
window.open("market://details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps","_system");
```

This is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501977/android-open-play-store-links-from-phonegap-app)

```
window.open('itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/domainsicle-domain-name-search/id511364723?ls=1&mt=8','_system');
```

set the map id. I don't know the market ID for map app for ios.

iOS example found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852804/how-to-implement-a-rate-us-feature-in-a-phonegap-app)

Comment: Hi Sir, it works on android. can you give me a sample market ID of an app in App Store so I have an idea what to find? Thanks.

Comment: you need to find the ID. `id511364723` use his one `id585027354`  `window.open('itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-maps/id585027354?ls=1&mt=8','_system');`